# Exclude resources from subdomain or only allow certain resources available to subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain, router

Rails 3, How would one exclude all controllers and methods from a subdomain and allow only certain resources specified under the subdomain block to be available?

Routes.rb:

```
< all regular resources >
match 'home/about' => "home#about"

  constraints subdomain: 'm' do
    resources :home
    resources :profile
    resources :messages
    root :to => 'mobile/home#index'

  end
```

I would like to disable m.domain.ltd/about which would be available in above setup. Is there an easy way to do this?